# transpose df group by column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I have a df like this :

| PRODUCTNUMBER | ATTRIBUTETYPENAME | TEXTVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ADAC5262** | **Genero** | **HOMBRE** |
| ADAC5262 | Marca | ADIDAS |
| ADAC5262 | Origen | NACIONAL |
| ADAC5262 | Tipo de Producto | MEDIAS |
| ADAC5262 | Color | AZUL+BLANCO |
| ADAC5262 | Proveedor | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A |
| ADAC5262 | Clase | ACCESORIOS |
| ADAC5262 | Categoria | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Edad | ADULTO |
| ADAC5262 | Banner | NA |
| ADAC5262 | Coleccion | SS2020 |
| ADAC5262 | Segmento | MEDIO |
| ADAC5262 | Linea de Producto | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Garantia del fabricante | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION |
| ADAC5262 | Matriz | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO |
| ADAC5262 | Talle proveedor | 1 |
| **ADAC5262** | **Genero** | **HOMBRE** |
| ADAC5262 | Marca | ADIDAS |
| ADAC5262 | Origen | NACIONAL |
| ADAC5262 | Tipo de Producto | MEDIAS |
| ADAC5262 | Color | AZUL+BLANCO |
| ADAC5262 | Proveedor | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A |
| ADAC5262 | Clase | ACCESORIOS |
| ADAC5262 | Categoria | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Edad | ADULTO |
| ADAC5262 | Banner | NA |
| ADAC5262 | Coleccion | SS2020 |
| ADAC5262 | Segmento | MEDIO |
| ADAC5262 | Linea de Producto | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Garantia del fabricante | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION |
| ADAC5262 | Matriz | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO |
| ADAC5262 | Talle proveedor | 2 |
| **ADAC5262** | **Genero** | **HOMBRE** |
| ADAC5262 | Marca | ADIDAS |
| ADAC5262 | Origen | NACIONAL |
| ADAC5262 | Tipo de Producto | MEDIAS |
| ADAC5262 | Color | AZUL+BLANCO |
| ADAC5262 | Proveedor | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A |
| ADAC5262 | Clase | ACCESORIOS |
| ADAC5262 | Categoria | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Edad | ADULTO |
| ADAC5262 | Banner | NA |
| ADAC5262 | Coleccion | SS2020 |
| ADAC5262 | Segmento | MEDIO |
| ADAC5262 | Linea de Producto | FUTBOL |
| ADAC5262 | Garantia del fabricante | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION |
| ADAC5262 | Matriz | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO |
| ADAC5262 | Talle proveedor | 4126 |

and I need to transpose and get as result:

| PRODUCTNUMBER | Genero | Marca | Origen | Tipo de Producto | Color | Proveedor | Clase | Categoria | Edad | Banner | Coleccion | Segmento | Linea de Producto | Garantia del fabricante | Matriz | Talle proveedor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADAC5262 | HOMBRE | ADIDAS | NACIONAL | MEDIAS | AZUL+BLANCO | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | ACCESORIOS | FUTBOL | ADULTO | NA | SS2020 | MEDIO | FUTBOL | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | 1 |
| ADAC5262 | HOMBRE | ADIDAS | NACIONAL | MEDIAS | AZUL+BLANCO | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | ACCESORIOS | FUTBOL | ADULTO | NA | SS2020 | MEDIO | FUTBOL | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | 2 |
| ADAC5262 | HOMBRE | ADIDAS | NACIONAL | MEDIAS | AZUL+BLANCO | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | ACCESORIOS | FUTBOL | ADULTO | NA | SS2020 | MEDIO | FUTBOL | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | 4126 |

Is it possible to transpose in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df.assign(tmp=df["ATTRIBUTETYPENAME"].eq("Genero").cumsum())
    .pivot(
        index=["tmp", "PRODUCTNUMBER"],
        columns="ATTRIBUTETYPENAME",
        values="TEXTVALUE",
    )
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="tmp")
)
df.columns.name = None
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| PRODUCTNUMBER | Banner | Categoria | Clase | Coleccion | Color | Edad | Garantia del fabricante | Genero | Linea de Producto | Marca | Matriz | Origen | Proveedor | Segmento | Talle proveedor | Tipo de Producto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADAC5262 | nan | FUTBOL | ACCESORIOS | SS2020 | AZUL+BLANCO | ADULTO | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | HOMBRE | FUTBOL | ADIDAS | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | NACIONAL | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | MEDIO | 1 | MEDIAS |
| ADAC5262 | nan | FUTBOL | ACCESORIOS | SS2020 | AZUL+BLANCO | ADULTO | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | HOMBRE | FUTBOL | ADIDAS | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | NACIONAL | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | MEDIO | 2 | MEDIAS |
| ADAC5262 | nan | FUTBOL | ACCESORIOS | SS2020 | AZUL+BLANCO | ADULTO | CONTRA DEFECTO DE FABRICACION | HOMBRE | FUTBOL | ADIDAS | OPORTUNIDAD REBAJADO | NACIONAL | 117 ADIDAS ARGENTINA S A | MEDIO | 4126 | MEDIAS |